# Not sure about grammar and tenses

Tags: grammar, verbs

These are the introductory sentences for my essay. It doesn't flow off my tongue - how can I improve it?

Any play is confined to a certain place, be it literally or figuratively. It is in this confinement where the story will unfold and the characters interact.

The word 'confined' must be in there. Here is the question that must be answered: ""Based on the discussion of the idea of confinement in Chapter Four of Introduction to English Literary Studies (IELS), write an essay of at least five paragraphs in which you discuss how the confinement of time and space enables the audience or reader to see more deeply into the nature of Elsa’s character during her visit to Miss Helen. You must make references to relevant aspects of the play to support your answer.

Comment: Do you want us to proofread these two sentences? What bothers you in particular?

Comment: Are the tenses correct? Is the grammar use correct? How does it flow from your tongue?

Comment: To me It doesn't! Why **confined**? Why **be it**? Why **interact**?

Comment: "**Any play literally or figuratively is tied to a certain place where the story unfolds and the characters interact"**. I don't have a clue what you mean by saying **interact**.

Comment: The word 'confined' must be in there.
Here is the question that must be answered:

""Based on the discussion of the idea of confinement in Chapter Four of Introduction to English
Literary Studies (IELS), write an essay of at least five paragraphs in which you discuss how the
confinement of time and space enables the audience or reader to see more deeply into the
nature of Elsa’s character during her visit to Miss Helen. You must make references to relevant
aspects of the play to support your answer.""""

Comment: Please include that in your question and don't forget to point out the problematic zones.

Comment: Edited. But I am not sure what you mean with 'problematic zones' Please help.

Comment: "It is in this confinement *that* ..." To me *confinement* is a situation, not a place. For example, if someone is confined in a jail, it is about the situation (they can't get out) rather than about the jail. But I think this is proofreading unless you tell us your specific concern, as opposed to the fact that it doesn't roll off your tongue nicely.

Comment: @SovereignSun: " I don't have a clue what you mean by saying interact". The verb "interact" means "act together"

Comment: Proof reading - what do you mean? Is there another place I must post for proofreading, or am I doing something wrong. Please assist.

Comment: Shall I perhaps just stick to: **Any play literally or figuratively is confined to a certain place where the story unfolds. **

Comment: @Rompey Thanks Rompey, but I know the definition, it's just that that verb doesn't seem to fit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on SovereignSun's comment, you could also write

> "Any play literally or figuratively is tied to a certain place where the story unfolds and the characters interact. This attribute is called confitement."

I posted an answer as I cannot comment here.